# Limit to number of videos that can be selected via buttons in kiosk?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, video, omxplayer, kiosk

I'll try to make this brief initially, in hopes that someone knows off the bat that there is some limit in omxplayer that I'm hitting. If not, I can post the code and more details about what I've tried. It has me stumped, but maybe I'm missing something.

NB: Using Pi 3, with Stretch and all updates.

I have a python script that uses omxplayer running in a museum kiosk. It runs a looping attractor video until one of 4 buttons is pushed, then plays whichever video was selected until that ends, then goes back to looping the attractor. Works flawlessly. Videos are all HD and range in length from 3 - 24 minutes.

I wanted to add 2 more videos. I added the buttons and extended the code for 2 more cases. However, when I choose one of the new videos, it starts but then quits and goes back to the attractor. Note that the videos are labelled movie_1.mp4 through movie_6.mp4. If I change the code so that one of the new buttons is set to play movie_1.mp4, it works, so the buttons are wired correctly. If I duplicate one of the original videos and name that, say movie_6.mp4, it breaks. It's like omxplayer somehow can't handle more than 4 videos, even though I don't see why it would care how many are in the list, since when a button is pushed, I kill any omxplayer processes that might be running and then start a new one.

I upped the GPU memory to 256, then 512, with no effect. The 4 videos were working fine with it set to the default 128.

File naming doesn't matter. If I rename movie_6.mp4 to boo.mp4, it still breaks. If I only add 1 new movie instead of 2, it breaks. If I change the code so that button 1 is calling for movie_6 and button 6 is calling for movie_1, then button 1 is now what breaks and button 6 works fine.

Note that I've tried turning on the --genlog option, but can't find that it's writing any output anywhere (looked in directory with the script, as well as /var/log/).

I've run out of ideas. Has anyone seen similar behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Good question and looks like you've done a lot of debugging already. Any chance you could post the python script?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the good news is that I solved the problem. The bad news is that I added noise to a great resource. Sorry for the distraction!

That said, posting the question and looking at the script *one* more time before responding to Roger's request to see it (Thanks, Roger!), made me look somewhere I hadn't -- the regex I use to test for whether a video is still playing or whether it's time to loop the attractor again. I had hard-wired where I shouldn't have (last-ditch coding before the exhibit launched).  Fixed that and now all is running as it should.

While I'm walking the Hall of Shame for Not-As-Sharp-As-They'd-Like-To-Be Programmers, I want to publicly thank Edgar Hucek, the omxplayer developer; Johneta and ThothLoki, whose scripts I tweaked for a button-driven player; and everyone who's on the web to help people and spread knowledge. On the shoulders of giants....